# Change the same text into index columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have this DataFrame, got from a group of same dataframe, but they have the same column name as `total_inflow` but I need change these name to indicate the different origin each other column as `total_inflow_t1`, `total_inflow_t2`, ...

So I have this:

```
In [227]: 
all = DataFrame([node_t1["total_inflow"], node_t2["total_inflow"], node_t3["total_inflow"], node_t4["total_inflow"], node_t5["total_inflow"]]).T



Out[227]:
    total_inflow    total_inflow    total_inflow    total_inflow    total_inflow
time                    
01/01/01 00:01:00   0.0085  0.0040  0.0002  0.0001  0.0001
01/01/01 00:02:00   0.2556  0.1669  0.0590  0.0012  0.0001
01/01/01 00:03:00   0.9935  0.7699  0.3792  0.0283  0.0002
01/01/01 00:04:00   1.3873  1.2879  0.8767  0.1614  0.0011
```

so I need to get this:

```
Out[227]:
    total_inflow_t1     total_inflow_t2     total_inflow_t3     total_inflow_t4     total_inflow_t5
time                    
01/01/01 00:01:00   0.0085  0.0040  0.0002  0.0001  0.0001
01/01/01 00:02:00   0.2556  0.1669  0.0590  0.0012  0.0001
01/01/01 00:03:00   0.9935  0.7699  0.3792  0.0283  0.0002
01/01/01 00:04:00   1.3873  1.2879  0.8767  0.1614  0.0011
```

Comment: if one of these answers solved your problem please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more generic solution. It will add a suffix to all the columns.

```
df.columns = ['{}_t{}'.format(k,i+1) for i,k in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

after you create your dataframe `all`, update the column names with:

```
all.columns = ['total_inflow_t1', 'total_inflow_t2', 'total_inflow_t3',
               'total_inflow_t4', 'total_inflow_t5']
```